# C++ delete operator on pointer, pointer not nulling

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer, delete-operator

I'm trying to implement a directed graph in C++. However, I'm having trouble with my RemoveEdge function, after I call the function and it uses the delete operator on the pointer and set the pointer to `nullptr`, it is not nulling outside the scope of the function.

I'm not sure if I've stated my problem clearly enough, but maybe some code will help.

**Graph.h**

```
template<class TVertex, class TEdge, class TWeight>
class Graph
{
protected:
    std::list<Vertex<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*>* _Vertices;
    std::list<Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*>* _Edges;
public:
    Graph();
    int TotalVertices();
    int TotalEdges();
    std::list<Vertex<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*>* Vertices();
    std::list<Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*>* Edges();

    Vertex<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* FindVertex(const TVertex&);
    Vertex<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* InsertVertex(const TVertex&);
    void RemoveVertex(const TVertex&);

    Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* FindEdge(const TEdge&);
    Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* InsertEdge(const TVertex&, const TVertex&, const TEdge&, const TWeight&);
    void RemoveEdge(const TEdge&);
};
```

**Graph.FindEdge()**

```
template<class TVertex, class TEdge, class TWeight>
Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* Graph<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>::FindEdge(const TEdge& label)
{
    Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* edge = nullptr;
    std::list<Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*>::iterator it;

    for(it = this->_Edges->begin(); it != this->_Edges->end(); ++it)
    {
        if(label == (*it)->Label())
        {
            edge = *it;
            break;
        }
    }

    return edge;
}
```

**Graph.RemoveEdge()**

```
template<class TVertex, class TEdge, class TWeight>
void Graph<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>::RemoveEdge(const TEdge& label)
{
    Edge<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>* edge = this->FindEdge(label);
    if(edge == nullptr)
        return;

    this->_Edges->remove(edge);
    edge->Source()->RemoveEdge(edge);
    edge->Destination()->RemoveEdge(edge);

            // Problem is here, why isn't this working like I think it should?
    delete edge;
    edge = nullptr;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
// created graph
// added vertices
// added edges
Edge<string, string, int>* e5 = graph->InsertEdge("Oshawa", "Toronto", "E5", 5);
graph->RemoveEdge("E5");
cout << ((e5 == nullptr) ? "null" : "not null") << endl; // this outputs not null
```

So as you can see my program crashes after I remove the edge from the graph, for some reason it is outputting `not null` after the RemoveEdge function is executed. I'm not sure why this is happening, I've used the delete operator and I've also nulled the pointer explicitly after. What am I doing wrong here?

And yes, I'm sure the edge is being found, the FindEdge function finds the correct edge object and removes it from the appropriate lists but the delete operator is not doing what I want it to do.

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: edge seems to be a local variable, which goes out of scope straight after it is 'nulled'.  Can you get a reference to the pointer back from FindEdge()?

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't that the point of using pointers so that I don't have to worry about the scope since it points to the memory location? Can you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: `int x = 5;  int* xp1 = &x;  int* xp2 = xp1;  xp2 = nullptr;`  . In this code, xp1 will not be a null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve updating of e5 outside the function you can use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`:

```
template<class TVertex, class TEdge, class TWeight>
class Graph
{
  typedef Vertex<TVertex,TEdge,TWeight> VextexType;
  typedef Edge<TVertex,TEdge,TWeight> EdgeType;

  typedef shared_ptr<VertexType> VertexPtr;
  typedef shared_ptr<EdgeType> EdgePtr;

protected:
    std::list< VertexPtr >* _Vertices;
    std::list< EdgePtr >* _Edges;
public:
    Graph();
    int TotalVertices();
    int TotalEdges();
    std::list<VertexPtr>* Vertices();
    std::list<EdgePtr>* Edges();

    VertexPtr FindVertex(const TVertex&);
    VertexPtr InsertVertex(const TVertex&);
    void RemoveVertex(const TVertex&);

    EdgePtr FindEdge(const TEdge&)
    {
        for( std::list<EdgePtr>::iterator it = this->_Edges->begin(); it != this->_Edges->end(); ++it)
        {
            if( label == (*it)->Label())
            {
                return *it;
            }
        }
        return EdgePtr();
    }

    EdgePtr InsertEdge(const TVertex&, const TVertex&, const TEdge&, const TWeight&);
    void RemoveEdge(const TEdge& label)
    {
        EdgePtr edge = this->FindEdge(label);
        if(!edge)
           return;

       this->_Edges->remove(edge);
       edge->Source()->RemoveEdge( edge.get() );
       edge->Destination()->RemoveEdge( edge.get() );
    }
};
```

Now you can write your section in main like this:

```
weak_ptr<Edge<string, string, int> > e5( graph->InsertEdge("Oshawa", "Toronto", "E5", 5) );
graph->RemoveEdge("E5");
cout << (e5 ? "null" : "not null") << endl;
```

Note that we use a weak_ptr to store the return value, rather than a shared_ptr.

Comment: Umm I see, I thought that it would null the memory location or something. Can you help me with the solution? How would I make it so that e5 is nulled from within the RemoveEdge function.

Comment: -1: The `RemoveEdge` does indeed remove the pointer from the collection so there is nothing there to null.

Comment: I don't see how your edit would work, plus I need it to be deleted in the RemoveEdge function, not the FindEdge function...

Comment: You're right .. dont know how I missed that RemoveEdge was actually doing the right thing .. I'll clean it all up again.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Thanks for the edited answer. I wish I had posted here sooner, I would've learnt about typedef's, it would've saved me a lot of writing lol. Shared/weak pointers are also new for me, I guess I will read up on them in the morning and start from scratch. Just one thing I would like to know, why did you say `this->_Edges->remove(edge);` the first time, and then `edge.get()` the next two times? The Edge->Source/Destination() methods return a Vertex that also maintains a list of EdgePtr's, and that's why I call on those two methods to remove all the object from all lists of edges.

Comment: @SaadImran. I used `remove(edge)` as `_Edges` is a list of `EdgePtr` (shared pointers). However I can't see/change the definition of what `Source()` and `Destination()` return - so I passed them a raw pointer - equivalent to what they were receiving in your original code. You may want to change them to accept weak or shared pointers later.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I see. Thanks a lot for your help! Will be learning a lot from it in the morning :)

Answer (score 5):

`e5` is a local variable which is different from `edge` in the class.

Both may point to the same object in memory, doesn't mean that if you make one null, the other would also point to null.

Consider this simple example,

```
int i = 10;
int *p1 = &i;
int *p2 = p1;

//here p1 and p2 points to the same object in memory which is i
p1 = nullptr; //it makes only p1 point to null

//here only p2 points to i
cout << *p2 << endl; //ok
cout << *p1 << endl; //dangerous - undefined behaviour!
```

I hope that helps you understanding the behaviour of your program!

---

Howevere, there is one trick you can do. Instead of using `T*`, if you use `T*&`, then you would get expected result:

```
Edge<string, string, int>* & e5 = graph->InsertEdge("Oshawa", "Toronto", "E5", 5);
//                         ^ see this

graph->RemoveEdge("E5");
cout << ((e5 == nullptr) ? "null" : "not null") << endl;
```

It should work because now `e5` is a reference to the object which is in the class, it no more a different object as such, it is more like an *alias* of the pointer which you create in `InsertEdge` and save in the list.

The analogous code using `i`, `p1` and `p2` would be this:

```
int i = 10;
int *p1 = &i;
int* & p2 = p1; //now it is a reference to p1, i.e an alias  of p1

//here p1 and p2 points to the same object in memory which is i

p1 = nullptr; //it makes only p1 point to null

//here both p1 and p2 points to null

 if ( p1 == nullptr)
       cout << "p1 points to null" << endl;
 if ( p2 == nullptr)
       cout << "p2 points to null" << endl;
 if ( p1 == p2)
       cout << "p1 and p2 are equal" << endl;
```

Output:

```
p1 points to null
p2 points to null
p1 and p2 are equal
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/ARiIl

Also note these:

```
//after p1 = nullptr
cout << *p2 << endl; //dangerous - undefined behaviour!
cout << *p1 << endl; //dangerous - undefined behaviour!
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm following what you've explained to me here so thanks for that. However, I have a problem, if I switch from T* to T*& like you suggested then I cannot return null values, which is neccessary for me. Is there any suggestion you have for that problem?

`Vertex<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>*& Graph<TVertex, TEdge, TWeight>::InsertVertex(const TVertex& label)` It won't let me return `nullptr` saying that it cannot convert between the two.

Comment: You'll need to be pretty careful that you dont end up with e5 being a dangling reference after the call to RemoveEdge.

Answer (score 1):

You do not null the pointer you create in your main.cpp. You're just nulling a pointer in your RemoveEdge method.

If you want to null the pointer in your main.cpp you could for example pass it to the RemoveEdge function and with this you could eliminate the need for searching inside your list.

Answer (score 1):

`edge` in `RemoveEdge` and `e5` in *Main.cpp* are two different local variables.
Assigning a value to one of them will not change the value of the other one.

Answer (score 1):

`FindEdge` returns a *copy* of the pointer present in the list which you are copying into *another copy* of the pointer (`edge` in `RemoveEdge`). So when you set this to `NULL` only this *copy* is modified, the pointer in the `list` is not affected.